# How to multiple select/picker custom field without parent-child relation?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

How can we create cascade select without parent - child relation ?

any example or turorial existed for this ?

It needs for below requirement:

I have created another customfield as like multiple input text box as shown below "filed2".

But unable to create "field1" and "field2" (shown below) and just getting stuck at select list control.

```
field1:                 <category1 select/picker> <category2 select> <category3 select>   <category4 picker>   //need to create

field2:  <input textbox>      <input textbox>     <input textbox>    <input textbox> 

field3 :  <resourece type picker>      <input textbox>     <input textbox>    <input   textbox>//need to create
```

If any one can suggest me  - can we extend existing cascadeselect (without parent - child) OR

directly use existing select list field inside custom field OR any tutorial/example will be appreciated.

it will be also fine to have static/non configurable values for these select picker list.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create two select custom fields and put them next to each other on the screens?

Comment: do you mean, without developing plugin ? if yes then, i did it by putting javascript on custom field description but UI just get destroy while do inline edit on issue view screen and not appear correctly how it should.  so, its better to create one custom field like that. Also, i need another custom field which contains static dropdown list inline with input text box as details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482619/facing-an-issue-in-jira-custom-field-creation..